# Error when inserting into database Django

Tags: python, django

I have a new problem, it is when I insert in the database the news, it adds but without the region. How can I insert the comment with the correct region?

Here is my view :

```
def index_region(request,region):
    try:
        actuCommentaire = Actu.objects.get(region=region)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        actuTempo = Actu(region=region)
        actuCommentaire = actuTempo.commentaire

    form = UpdateActu(request.POST or None, instance=actuCommentaire)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('index.html')
```

Here is my model "Actu" :

```
class Actu(models.Model):
    commentaire = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region
```

Here is my form :

```
class UpdateActu(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Actu
        fields = ['commentaire']
        widgets = {
            'commentaire': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'exampleTextarea', 'rows': '2'})
        }
```

Here is the result when inserting into the database :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNw98.png)

Comment: Your `region` is a string? Usually I would say one models this with a `Region` model.

Comment: Can you explain how you insert values here?

Comment: There is something rather strange. You perform a `.get(..)` on the region. But that means that your view makes the assumptions that `region`s are unique.

Comment: I insert my values ​​using the form that includes only the "commentaire" field. I want the person who writes the "commentaire" and when validates the insertion with the "commentaire" and region of the "commentaire" using the parameter in the function.

Comment: Yes, but right now we have no access to that form, etc. So perhaps it is good to share the form and the POST request you've made.

Comment: Yes, the region is unique.

Comment: I add my form just at the top.

Comment: I have a total of 8 regions.

Comment: You've added the view, but you should add the form part of the template that sends the post data

Comment: I edited my question just above

Comment: I find it a bit weird that your view has a `region` paramater. Why is it not part of the `POST` (or `GET` parameters).

Comment: Because I use the "region" parameter for something else. But how can I do with your solution ?

Comment: You need to pass the "region" either as a query parameter like-"http:/localhost:8000/actu?region=France" or pass it in request data itself in case of POST request.

Comment: It's good, I managed thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve the problem.

Here is my new view :

```
try:
    actuCommentaire = Actu.objects.get(region=region)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    actuTempo = Actu(region=region)
    actuCommentaire = actuTempo.commentaire

form = UpdateActu(request.POST or None, instance=actuCommentaire)

if form.is_valid():
    if Actu.objects.filter(region=region).count() == 0:
        formActu = Actu(commentaire=request.POST['commentaire'], region=region)
        formActu.save()
    else:
        form.save()
    return redirect('index.html')
```